# Email template not rendering correctly in Mail (iPad)

Tags: html, css, email, templates, html-email

Now the issue I am having seems to be possibly with email sizing within Mail Client on iOS on the iPad. Although this template seems to look ok in all clients, the result I am getting in Mail Client on Iphone looks compressed

Email template rendering in Mail:
[image: Email template rendering in Mail:]

Email template rendering in other clients:
[image: Email template rendering in other clients]

Html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <title>Rater8.Performance Scorecard</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none;}

        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 600px), only screen and (min-width: 600px) { 
            .table_logo {
                min-height: 80px;
            }   
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="padding:0; margin:0px;">
    
        
            
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width: 620px; width: 100%; line-height: 1.1em; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; background-color: #fff;">
                    <tr><td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 12px; text-align: left;">Hi <span>{FirstName}</span>,</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 12px; text-align: left;">Your rater8 Performance Scorecard for the month of <span>{MonthAndYear}</span> is ready!</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 12px; text-align: left;">Please click on this <a href="{EmailLinkCode}" style="color: #4285F4;">link</a> to view your complete scorecard. If you have any questions, please ask your practice administrator or email <a style="color: #4285F4;" href="mailto:support@rater8.com">support@rater8.com</a>.</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center">
                            
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                            <tr>
                            <td width="22%" style="width: 22%; border: 1px solid #CACACA; padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                            <div style="border: 1px solid #CACACA; min-height: 246px; padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px; display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 3px; margin-right: 3px; text-align: left;">
                                <table   width="180" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 180px;" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left"> 
                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 180px;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 3px; text-align: center;"><img src=cid:logoLR width="100"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-right: 5px;"><img width="65" height="65" style="border-radius: 50%; overflow: hidden;" src=cid:{imgCId}></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1em; font-weight: 500;">{UserName}</span><br /><span style="font-size: 12px;  line-height: 1em; color:#BDBDBD;">{JobTitle}</span><br /><span style="font-size: 12px;  line-height: 1em; color:#BDBDBD;">{TenantName}</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; padding-top: 15px; text-align: center;">
                                                    <span>{AverageRating}</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding-top: 15px;">
                                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="font-size: 14px;">
                                                        <tr><td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 7px;">{RatingsCount}</td><td style="padding-left: 5px;">Ratings</td></tr>
                                                        <tr><td style="text-align: right; padding-left: 7px;">{ReviewsCount}</td><td style="padding-left: 5px;">Comments</td></tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="text-align: center;"><img width="30" height="30" src=cid:{firstStar}></td>
                                                            <td style="text-align: center;"><img width="30" height="30" src=cid:{secondStar}></td>
                                                            <td style="text-align: center;"><img width="30" height="30" src=cid:{thirdStar}></td>
                                                            <td style="text-align: center;"><img width="30" height="30" src=cid:{fourthStar}></td>
                                                            <td style="text-align: center;"><img width="30" height="30" src=cid:{fifthStar}></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><![endif]-->
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><td width="78%" valign="middle" style="width: 78%; border: 1px solid #CACACA; vertical-align: middle; padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px"><![endif]-->
                            <div style="display: inline-block;  text-align: left; min-height: 246px; min-width: 68%;">
                            <table border="0" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="max-width: 423px; width: 100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <table class="table_logo" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" border="0" style="width: 100%;" >
                                            <tr>
                                                {blockTemplate} 
                                            </tr> 
                                        </table> 
                                        <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <tr>
                                            <td style="border: 1px solid #CACACA; padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px;">
                                                <table class="table"  cellspacing="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td style="background-color: #95B3D7; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; text-align: right; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{MonthAndYear}</td>
                                                        <td style="background-color: #95B3D7; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; text-align: right; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Since Go-Live</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Review Requests Sent</td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{SurveysSentPastMonth}</td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{SurveysSentAllTime}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Review Requests Responded</td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{SurveysRespondedPastMonth}</td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{SurveysRespondedAllTime}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Response Rate</td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ResponseRatePastMonth}</td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ResponseRateAllTime}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Online Review Site Redirects</td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ReviewRedirectionsPastMonth}</td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ReviewRedirectionsAllTime}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Online Reviews Added</td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ExternalReviewsAddedPastMonth}</td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #DBE5F1;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ExternalReviewsAddedAllTime}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFFF; padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">Conversion Rate</td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ConversionRatePastMonth}</td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #B4C9E3; background-color: #FFF;  padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 11px;">{ConversionRateAddedAllTime}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></tr></td><![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {blockComments}
                    <!-- end main -->
                    <tr><td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 12px; padding-top: 12px; text-align: left;">Best regards,</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 12px; text-align: left;">The rater8 Data Analytics Team</td></tr>
                </table>
            
        
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've mentioned iPad in the title, but iPhone in the description? Are you seeing the issue on both devices? If so, that could mean a wider reaching issue. If just the  iPhone, it could be your content not being flexible for smaller screens to adapt the width of your email. Hard to test with your data variables in the code though as the label text cannot wrap. Would be good if you can provide an example of the final code for a full test...?

Comment: The basic thing to do, to find out which part is too wide for it, is to remove a section at a time, and see what fixes it. It's probably the big table, which it struggles to compress.

Answer (score 0):

The structure created by you is not correct.

Some of the issues are:

1. Use XHTML 1 instead of HTML 4

HTML 4 is not to be used.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

XHTML 1 should be used.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

2. Giving table width in % is the wrong use

   ```
   <table width"700">
   ```

   and "td" with width.

Please find the working example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.`enter code here`dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Request Payment</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#2a323d">
  <table width="698" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-radius: 6px; border: 1px solid #eee;">
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center" height="37">
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/220/62" width="220" height="62" border="0" alt="CreditCard.com" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center" height="31">
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" height="1" style="border-top: 1px solid #eee;">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center" height="80">
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/241/197" width="241" height="197" border="0" alt="Request Payment" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center" height="60">
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center">
        <font face="helvetica" size="5" color="#252d38">
          <b>Payment Request !</b>
        </font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center" height="10">
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center">
        <table width="698" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="70" align="center" rowspan="5">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="558" align="center">
              <font face="helvetica" color="#252d38" style="font-size:22px;">
                XYZ is requesting you for the payment of <b>$250</b> against the reference no. <b>236832</b>.
              </font>
            </td>
            <td width="70" align="center" rowspan="5">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="558" align="center" height="20">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="558" align="center">
              <font face="helvetica" color="#7b7b7b" style="font-size:18px;">
                Please ignore in case you have already paid.
              </font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="558" align="center" height="60">
              &nbsp;
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="558" align="center">
              <table width="558" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="69" align="center">
                    &nbsp;
                  </td>
                  <td width="200" align="center">
                    <a href="http://www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none;">
                      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/60" width="200" height="60" border="0" alt="Decline Payment" />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td width="20" align="center">
                    &nbsp;
                  </td>
                  <td width="200" align="center">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration: none;">
                      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/60" width="200" height="60" border="0" alt="Make Payment" />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td width="69" align="center">
                    &nbsp;
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center" height="70">
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" height="2" style="border-top: 1px solid #eee;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center" height="10">
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
          <font face="helvetica" size="1" color="#7b7b7b">
            Privacy Policy
          </font>
        </a>
        <font face="helvetica" size="1" color="#7b7b7b">
          &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        </font>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
          <font face="helvetica" size="1" color="#7b7b7b">
            Terms & Conditions
          </font>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="698" align="center" height="10">
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not right. Use of 100% is good, and when you use large widths, that is known to cause these sorts of scaling issues in mobiles (which attempt to fit into approx 300px wide screens)

Comment: @Nathan it is true for the web but not for email templates. In email templates, we use fixed-width so that it won't break in any device. There are some rules for it. Only the outer div or table tags can have the width in %. For email template rules, please refer to https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/html/.

Comment: Sorry mate, even your example contradicts what you have said. So, you have a 100% on the outermost table/div, as you say. Then your overall desired width, e.g. 600 or 698 in this case. Then after that, everything should be percentage-based again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your email template. it will resolve most of the issues

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Email Sample</title>
        <style>
            /* your css code with media queries */
        </style>
    </head>
```

I hope this will help you.